# Perl XML::LibXML Parser Error

Tags: xml, perl

If I am using the XML::LibXML parser to repeatedly call a line like the following...

```
$tree = $parser->parse_file($WBCall);
```

...where $WBCall represents a HTTP string to a service that returns data in XML format, then occasionally I receive an error like the following: ":1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found"

This occurs rarely when the code is pulling in hundreds of XML data files. Does this mean that I need to add in some XML validation? If so, what's the best Perl module for that?

Comment: What do you mean? If it doesn't parse, then you've validated that it's not valid. If you want to catch the error, use eval: my $document = eval { $parser->parse_file($WBCall) } or warn "Error: $@"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're occasionally getting a response with an empty body, or possibly some sort of "server busy" response.

When you say "*$WBCall represents a HTTP string to a service that returns data in XML format*" do you mean that it contains a URI?  If so, perhaps you could make the HTTP request yourself using LWP and then call `$parser->parse_string($response->content)`. In the event of an error (catch it with eval) you could log `$response->as_string`.